# Using load() by second session factory in my project throws org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no session error

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, sessionfactory

I implemented the two session factories in my spring hibernate project.

why is it happening, when i use the first session factory for load() it works fine but when i use second session factory for load method it returns the org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no session  error.

Comment: LazyInitializationException is thrown when you are trying to access the relational entity that has been marked as LAZY loadable.

Comment: By the first session factory it does not throw any error but the same entity with the second session factory it throws LazyInitializationException - no session.

Comment: Can you share the code for entity model and loading the entity

Comment: It happened with all entity models of the projects. With FIRST SESSION FACTORY it is working properly but don't know why when i used the second session factory it returns this error.

Comment: Accodring to me, so far i come to know that the sessionHolder (in HibernateTransactionObject class),it is null for the second transaction manager(i.e. for second session factory)whereas for first transacion manager, the session holder is not null.And so by using load() with secondsesionfactory the session gets closed due to sessionHolder and gives me this lazy exception. But don't know why sessionHolder is null????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution of the above problem. you need to create open session in view for second session factory also and to create the open session in view for second session factory.In web.xml configuration of open session in view for both session factories is required.